# How to overcome java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError in hadoop

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop, jar

I'm getting IncompatibleClassChangeError :: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but class was expected.I had used shaded plugin and Main class plugin i.e,

```
  Mainclass plugin:
==================     

 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.calsoftlabs.ndt.PcapMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

shaded plugin:
============
    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                            signed jars
                                 <excludes>
                                    <exclude>bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>

                             <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    Main class
                                    <mainClass>com.calsoftlabs.ndt.PcapMain</mainClass>
                                </transformer>

                         </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I got two jars :
1) original-PCAPSample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  -->due to shaded plugin
2) PCAPSample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  -->due to Main class plugin

--->when I used shaded plugin jar I'm getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pcap

---> when I used 2nd jar I'm getting IncompatibleClassChangeError

--->Actually I'm trying to use pcapInputFormat class from this url https://github.com/RIPE-NCC/hadoop-pcap/blob/master/hadoop-pcap-lib/src/main/java/net/ripe/hadoop/pcap/io/PcapInputFormat.java

---> I had added hadoop-pcap-lib(from above specified url) dependency in my pom.xml and trying to use that PcapInputFormat

--->what can I do now in order to overcome this problem.Can anyone suggest on this issue ...

Answer (score 0):

`TaskAttemptContext` changed from a class in Hadoop 1 to an interface in Hadoop 2.  It's pretty clear that the jar you're using was built against the Hadoop 1 API, and despite their claims to the contrary, Hadoop 2 is not backward compatible for any but the simplest of applications.

Comment: How can I overcome this issue now

Comment: Is there any way to solve this problem .what things can I do now? please suggest me

Comment: I think the jar dependency is a red herring here.  What other code is involved?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to parse the mlab ndt trace log files.For  parsing purpose I'm using PcapInputFormat class.In order to include that class I had cloned hadoop-pcap-lib project from github and I had added dependency of that github project into my current project.                                                                                                          I used   job.setInputFormatClass(PcapInputFormat.class);   by importing net.ripe.hadoop.pcap.io.PcapInputFormat;

Comment: How to go ahead now.can u tell me please